# Counting Contents in a zipped file

Tags: powershell

How do I count the files within a zipped folder?

What I have so far is:

```
gci $path | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

This query does give me the latest zip file, which is what I want. What I need now is to count the items inside and I have no clue.

Output:

```
12/29/2018  10:48 PM  841969343 2018-12-29T22-42-26_EDM_PROD_Databases.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the System.IO.Compression assembly with

```
add-type -AssemblyName system.io.compression.filesystem
```

and open the zip-file using [ZipFile.OpenRead(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.openread?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
$archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead("D:\monitoringsolution.zip")
```

This will return a [ZipArchive]-object that has a property called 'Entries' [ZipArchive.Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries?view=netframework-4.7.2). This property is self-explanatory ;)

```
write-host ($archive.entries.count)
```